# Is there a Java SDK for azure machine learning service?

Tags: azure, azure-java-sdk, azure-machine-learning-service

Is there a Java SDK for Azure Machine Learning service? If not, is there a way to create Azure ML pipelines, experiments etc from Java codebase?

Answer (score 2):

No, today there is only a SDK for Python. Alternatively you could use the Azure CLI extension for ML which you could call from your Java code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/reference-azure-machine-learning-cli

Answer (score 0):

The `Azure Machine Learning Studio` directly supports only `R & Python`.
There is *no way to handle Azure ML pipelines with java* code at the moment.

However, you can consume **Azure Cognitive Services** (which provides pre-trained models) through the exposed **Java** API.

Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/data-guide/technology-choices/data-science-and-machine-learning) for more details.